# Can I set Email Subject Line in Template?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

I'm struggling to find a way to set a subject line in the email template, is this not possible?  Ultimately, I will be pulling the subject line from a data extension with some ampscript (and to do that, I need to set the ampscript variable in the subject line in the template) but I'm not seeing a way to set any subject line at the template level.  Is this really not possible?

Comment: Just a heads-up - it can be helpful to tag your question with, for example, `marketing-cloud` or `ampscript` to make the context clear, since email templates can apply to several different Salesforce products.

Comment: Thanks David - I didn't realize that.  Yes - this is a marketing cloud question.  Appreciate it!

Comment: If you are anyway pulling the subject line from a DE, why you want to set on the template?

Comment: Hi Maneesh - I wanted to establish the mapping of the DE column to the subject line in the template so my marketing team didn't have to re-map this variable every time they create a new email from template.  Sounds like this is not an option...but feels like a logical enhancement to the product.

Answer (score 3):

The templates in Marketing Cloud doesn't include the subject definition meaning that you will always need to create an email to set-up the subject.

You can assign the subject text to a variable using ampscript in the template and then, once you create the email based on that template, you just have to put the variable in the subject field. `%%=v(@subject)=%%`

Comment: Yeah - I found that too.  I was hoping to set everything in the template dynamically (pulling from data extensions) so my marketing team could simply create a new email from template, add the correct naming convention & audience segment & save/send.  This adds a couple extra steps (they will have to map in the subject line and leader line).  If that's the way it is...I guess that's all we can do.  Seems like a logical enhancement though.

Answer (score 0):

You may use setSubject method in Apex

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single

Comment: From what  I can tell, this answer does not apply to the email template in Marketing Studio?  I'm looking to create template based emails from a template in marketing studio...but can't see a way to assign a subject line (or an ampscript parameter) at the template level.

Comment: Apex isn't supported by Marketing Cloud Env.

Comment: This answer would be correct if the question would be about email template in other salesforce clouds - but as the question was edited to show it’s a marketing cloud specific question- I agree this is not the answer.